# Can't change imported blender object material color by script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender

I'm trying to apply a script that changes the material color when the cursor is on top of the object. Here's the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeColor : MonoBehaviour {

    public Color startColor;
    public Color mouseOverColor;
    bool mouseOver = false;


    void OnMouseEnter(){
        Debug.Log("START");
        mouseOver = true;
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color",mouseOverColor);
        Debug.Log("TESTE");
    }

    void OnMouseExit(){
        mouseOver = false;
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", startColor);
    }

}
```

This code works perfectly when applied to a cube created with unity, but when I try to use it on a imported mesh, it doesn't work.

Here's an example of one of the imported objects where the script doesn't work:
[image]

Can someone help me understand how can I solve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your imported meshes don't have a collider yet which is required for the mouse detect.

Add one, for a simple mesh like a sphere just use a `Sphere Collider`.

Edit:
Also, you should usually store a reference if you need to access it frequently.

```
private Renderer rend;

private void Awake()
{
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
}
```

Comment: That was exacly the problem, thank you! Just one more thing: it works with a sphere collider, but when I use a mesh or a cube collider, it doesn't. Why is that?

Comment: @vasco_t I can't tell that without any more information. I would suggest opening a new question for that with some screenshots with working/not working objects. Generally all of them will work. Just did a little test for myself with a mesh collider and had no problems.